# Does Java Thread.sleep() release the processor?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, thread-safety, cpu

I have CPUx2 in a server and I have a program that included many threads, if all threads take a long time to do something, is it possible to use Thread.Sleep(10) in order to let CPU release job into another threads? Could I just use thread.sleep and will it let CPU to auto switch another threads in order to improve or enhance the performance?

UPDATED at 2016/06/06:
Every thread is focusing on obtain HTTP content from the Internet with Executors, while I want to give it delay more time to do, but I am not so sure when I added TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10) in the code inside whether use either MILLISECONDS or NANOSECOND and with how many time slot that let CPU to auto switch another threads, so that the overall performance can be fair:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    //this.RunActual = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ("Started".equals(this.JobStatus)) {
        String startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " has started at " + startDate);
        try {
            this.url = new URL("http://" + this.HttpRequestAddress + ":" + this.HttpRequestPort);
            this.conn = (HttpURLConnection) this.url.openConnection();
            this.conn.setRequestMethod(this.HttpRequestMethod);
            this.conn.setReadTimeout(this.HttpRequestReadTimeout);
            this.conn.setConnectTimeout(this.HttpRequestConnectionTimeout);
            this.conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            for (HttpHeader hh : this.HttpRequestHeader) {
                this.conn.setRequestProperty(hh.Name, hh.Value);
            }
            this.conn.connect();
            this.responseCode = 0;
            this.responseCode = this.conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " has response header " + this.conn.getHeaderFields().toString());
            if (this.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                if (this.HttpResponseKeyword != null) {
                    boolean hasKeyword = false;
                    this.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.conn.getInputStream(), this.httpResponseEncoding));
                    while ((this.charRead = this.br.read(this.buffer, 0, this.BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
                        this.sb.append(this.buffer, 0, this.charRead);
                        //System.out.println(this.sb.toString());
                        if (this.HttpResponseContain && this.sb.indexOf(this.HttpResponseKeyword) > 0) {
                            hasKeyword = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        this.sb.setLength(0);
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
                    }
                    if (this.HttpResponseContain && hasKeyword) {
                        System.out.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " should include keyword, now it is included.");
                    } else if (this.HttpResponseContain && !hasKeyword) {
                        System.out.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " should include keyword, but it is not included.");
                    } else if (!this.HttpResponseContain && !hasKeyword) {
                        System.out.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " should not include keyword, now it is not included.");
                    } else if (!this.HttpResponseContain && hasKeyword) {
                        System.out.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " should not include keyword, but it is included.");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String errorDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            System.err.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " has error at " + errorDate + " with " + ex.toString());
        }
        String endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " has end at " + endDate);
    }

    /*
    if (this.RunNext != 0) {
        long c = this.RunActual - this.RunNext;
        if (c > 0) {
            System.out.println(this.HttpRequestAddress + " has slowed " + c + " milliseconda.");
        }
    }*/

    //this.RunNext = System.currentTimeMillis() + this.JobInterval;
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad. It depends on what the threads are doing. Some may question why you are using a lot of threads. Please show a code example of your problem that expresses your issue

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? If the threads are using your CPU 100%, then they are running as fast as they can, and adding `sleep()` will not help overall performance. The jobs still have to be done. Are you trying to "throttle" them, slowing them down so they use less CPU? Why? If you simply want other programs to run normally, lower the thread priority of your threads. That way they will use all available CPU, but still allow other programs to run with minimal delay.

Comment: There is almost never any good reason to call `Thread.sleep()`.  If you are using it in a real-time application to make things happen at the right moments, then you would be better off using something like the standard JRE's `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` class or some GUI framework's `Timer` class.  If you are using it to balance the amount of work done by different threads, then there's probably some other, better way.  If you are using it to make sure things happen in the right order, then you probably are making a terrible mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you surmise, calling `Thread.sleep()` releases the processor in most major operating systems.  However, you do not need to call `Thread.sleep()` to release the processor on most operating systems, as the operating system will switch to other threads at intervals anyway.  Using `Thread.sleep()` may improve efficiency relative to a loop that constantly checks for a completion condition, but a better solution is often to use waits and notifies so the thread can wake up when needed rather than having to check at intervals.

Answer (score 7):

`Thread.sleep()` releases the processor to another runnable thread or process and marks the current thread as not runnable until the sleep time expires.

HOWEVER, and *in re* your edit, your code will spend most of its time blocked while reading from the network. Adding sleeps into this code is completely pointless. Don't. The operating system already knows how to schedule, and TCP already knows how to share bandwidth.